# How do I run a function in a differnent document on a menu button

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to run the script so when a menu item is clicked, a function that creates a text box is run. I can't figure out how not to only split up my documents in google app script and running a function from the menu.

I tried to place the function within the menu item, but it is not speaking to the other document.

#### menu.js.gs

```js
function onOpen() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
    ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
        .addItem('First item', 'menuItem1')
        .addSeparator()
        .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Sub-menu')
            function addTextBox(presentationId, pageId)
        .addToUi();
}

function menuItem1() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
        .alert('You clicked the first menu item!');
}

function menuItem2() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
        .alert('You clicked the second menu item!');
}
```

#### textbox.js.gs

```js
/**
    * Add a new text box with text to a page.
    * @param {string} presentationId The presentation ID.
    * @param {string} pageId The page ID.
    */x
function addTextBox(presentationId, pageId) {
    // You can specify the ID to use for elements you create,
    // as long as the ID is unique.
    var pageElementId = Utilities.getUuid();

    var requests = [{
    'createShape': {
        'objectId': pageElementId,
        'shapeType': 'TEXT_BOX',
        'elementProperties': {
        'pageObjectId': pageId,
        'size': {
            'width': {
            'magnitude': 150,
            'unit': 'PT'
            },
            'height': {
            'magnitude': 50,
            'unit': 'PT'
            }
        },
        'transform': {
            'scaleX': 1,
            'scaleY': 1,
            'translateX': 200,
            'translateY': 100,
            'unit': 'PT'
        }
        }
    }
    }, {
    'insertText': {
        'objectId': pageElementId,
        'text': 'My Added Text Box',
        'insertionIndex': 0
    }
    }];
    var response =
        Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({'requests': requests}, presentationId);
    Logger.log('Created Textbox with ID: ' +
        response.replies[0].createShape.objectId);
}
```

Comment: If textbox.js.gs is in one app, I think it can call each one, but we will call it  directly, not call with function again. Please try to remove function i your call "function addTextBox(presentationId, pageId)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('First item', 'menuItem1')
      .addSeparator()
      .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Sub-menu')
            function addTextBox(presentationId, pageId)
      .addToUi();
}
```

Should be like this:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
  .addItem('First item Title', 'menuItem1')
  .addSubMenu(SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("My SubMenu")
  .addItem('Add Text Box','addTextBox'))
  .addToUi();
  //With other functions below this
}
```

But unfortunately you can't use functions with parameters in menus.